# WIX: How can I queue custom action between "after InstallFile" and "before "XMLFile" ?

Tags: wix, custom-action, wix3

I have a custom action that dynamically generates an XML file based on installed files (can't change this utility). The custom action must execute after "InstallFiles".

I would like to use XMLFile to make other modifications to the XML file based on other features installed.

Any suggestions on how to schedule custom action between "after=InstallFile" and "before "XMLFile" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
<Custom action="CustomizingXMLData" after="InstallFiles">Condition</Custom>

<Custom action="XMLFile" after="CustomizingXMLData">Condition</Custom>
```

Comment: Thanks  I forgot about setting  the action.